# Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps in .NET

Tags: android, .net, token, backend, verification

Is there a .net code sample that implements a google access Token checker.

there is an example in java there:
http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

I just can't find any straight foward example to do this in .net.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way.

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;

JwtSecurityTokenHandler jsh = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
SecurityToken st = jsh.ReadToken(token);
string tokenString = st.ToString();
```

in tokenString look for tag azp.